# Can someone please explain why I'm getting an error in this code

Tags: java, class, constructor, illegalargumentexception

I'm making an throw `IllegalArgumentException` statement in my constructor class of my classs to check if the user's input's age is higher than the `maxAge` wanted. I'm using if statements to throw the `IllegalArgumentException` at the user if the age entered is higher than the `maxAge`. The error the IDE is giving me is an `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I have tried to declare and assign the values outside the if statement like

```
int timePeriod = (Period.between(bday, LocalDate.now()).getYears()); 
int maxAge = 101;
```

to check if Im still getting the error. it seems like the problem is in the `periods.between >> getYear` statement.

Code:

```
    public Instructor(String fname, String lname, int ID, String road, String cty, String postalCode, LocalDate reg, LocalDate bDay) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {   
        int timePeriod = (Period.between(bday, LocalDate.now()).getYears());
        int maxAge = 101; 
        System.out.print(timePeriod);
        //if (101 < (Period.between(bday, LocalDate.now()).getYears())) { 
        if (maxAge < timePeriod) { 

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please check the year entered, instructor cannot be over 100 years old.");
        } 
        else { 
            this.first = fname;
            this.last = lname;
            this.instructID = ID; 
            this.address = road;
            this.city = cty;
            this.postCode = postalCode;
            this.regDate = reg;
            this.bday = bDay;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: working fine for me I guess there must be some param that is null

Comment: When you have an error that gives a stacktrace, show the stacktrace and identify the line from your code that's identified in the stacktrace. Don't just tell us the name of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Period.between(null, LocalDate.now());
```

Above code line will throw

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Try passing non-null value in startDate and also add null checks in your code to avoid any such exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are using the instance variable bday instead of the passed parameter bDay. bday has not been created yet and as such does not exist.

I suggest that you be extremely careful with close variable names like that. It will save you a lot of trouble as your projects get bigger and more complex.

Comment: Yeah, bday must have been declared earlier, or there would have been a compile error, so we don't know where it's used, and having a null value would fit the circs.